# End of day receipt emailing process

Tags: beginner, vba, error-handling, excel

The following functions/routines are an automation of an end of day receipt emailing process that formerly would take up to an hour, but now takes less than a minute.

Things to note: I changed the name of some of a variable or two in order to protect the identity of the company that this is being used for.  THe vast majority of the variables/objects are uneffected, but several have had to be changed.  I am also aware of the ability to change worksheet code names so that they can be utilized like Global Variables, but I am hesistant to change code names for sheets in this specific workbook because there are a lot of other macros that have been written by someone else and i'm not sure how they manipulate the existing worksheet objects.  I am confident these worksheet names will never change.

I am open to any and all criticism, especially on how to do things more efficiently and cleanly.  I am still fairly new to VBA and i'm looking to write like a professional.  I would love to utilize arrays more often, but i'm not quite sure how to search through their contents or how to organize them well.  I've only used them to store product codes and things like that to iterate through an array with an index counter.  I'd also like some pointers on error handling!

**Clarifying the Processes:** This code runs off of a main sheet that lists business conducted for the day by client, `ReportsByFirmSheet`, and generates receipt emails for each client that did business with the company utilizing the sheets.  These emails have a general static body that does not change (the to field changes dependent upon the client) and have PDF receipts attached (clients may have multiple receipts throughout the day). `ControlPanelSheet` is merely the main driving sheet of the workbook where most of the macro execution abilities are stored for client side use. `TradesMasterSheet` is a big running sheet of raw business data (`RepotsByFirmSheet` is a less detailed summation of those business transactions).  `ContactsMaster`, which is not defined (because I was able to change the codename for that one) is where all of the email contact information and client specifics are stored.

An improvement I had considered, but was unsure how to implement, was to minimize the iteration through reports by firm to one run by naming and creating multiple email objects and allocating the specific receipts to each mail object rather than repetitively iterating through the sheet and creating emails for one client at a time.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const EMAIL_BODY As String = "Hello," & "<br><br>" & "Please find today's business receipt's attached.  Thank you." & "<br><br>" & "Best Regards," & "<br>"
Public Const PDF_FILE_PATH As String = "X:\Back Office\Receipt Drop File\"
Public Const EXCEL_CONFIRM_FILE_PATH As String = "X:\Back Office\Receipt Drop File\Excel Receipt Drop File\"
Public Const CME_DESIGNATION As String = "_vs._NYMEX"
Public Const ICE_DESIGNATION As String = "_vs._ICE"
Dim FormattedReportDate As String
Dim ReportsByFirmSheet As Worksheet, ControlPanelSheet As Worksheet, TradesMasterSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub SendPdfEmails()
'Sends PDF emails to clients
'Version 2
'Written by Storms Edge
'Project start 3/1/2016

    Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim eeBook As Workbook
    Dim firmAlreadyRun As Boolean, isTraderSeparate As Boolean, firmNeedExcelConfirm As Boolean, productSeparatedEmails As Boolean
    Dim activeWorkbookName As String, currentFirmName As String, currentTraderName As String, firmEmail As String, firmName1 As String, firmName2 As String, firmName3 As String
    Dim lastRowReportsByFirmSheet As Long, lRowContactsMasterSheet As Long, reportsByFirmRowCounter As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    activeWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set eeBook = Workbooks(activeWorkbookName)
    Set ReportsByFirmSheet = eeBook.Sheets("ReportsbyFirm")
    Set ControlPanelSheet = eeBook.Sheets("Control Panel")
    Set TradesMasterSheet = eeBook.Sheets("Trades Master List")
    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo Bail_Out

    'Sets Date parameters in Reports by firm and ensures date linkage between reports by firm and control panel by running control panel routine
    ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(1, 2) = ControlPanelSheet.Cells(7, 6)
    ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(2, 2) = ControlPanelSheet.Cells(7, 6)
    FormattedReportDate = Replace(Format(Range("printinvdate"), "m/d/yy"), "/", ".")

    Call gen_report

    'finds last row to create end bound of for loop iteration through Reports By Firm Sheet
    lastRowReportsByFirmSheet = ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(ReportsByFirmSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Iterates through reports by firm and steps down each row to capture all firms and generate emails
    For reportsByFirmRowCounter = 11 To lastRowReportsByFirmSheet

        currentFirmName = ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 5).Value
        currentTraderName = ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 6).Value

        'Tests to see if firm was already run and subsequently if the emp was already run if annotated that emp is seperate in memory manager area
        firmAlreadyRun = FirmDidRun(currentFirmName, currentTraderName, ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 3).Value)

        'Skips iteration process and moves to next if firm/trader has already been run
        If firmAlreadyRun = True Then GoTo skipIteration

        firmEmail = GetFirmEmailInfo(reportsByFirmRowCounter, currentFirmName, currentTraderName, isTraderSeparate, firmNeedExcelConfirm, firmName1, firmName2, firmName3, productSeparatedEmails)

        'tests firmEmail for clients who do not receive emailed confirms
        If firmEmail = "NO" Then GoTo skipIteration

        'Creates new email object
        Set outMail = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Call BuildAddressMailItem(outMail, firmEmail, FormattedReportDate)

        Call GetPDFConfirms(outMail, firmEmail, firmName1, firmName2, firmName3, currentTraderName, isTraderSeparate, productSeparatedEmails, reportsByFirmRowCounter, lastRowReportsByFirmSheet)

        If firmNeedExcelConfirm = True Then

            Call GetExcelConfirms(outMail, currentFirmName, firmName1, firmName2, firmName3)

        End If

        outMail.Display

        Call MemoryManager(firmName1, firmName2, firmName3, currentTraderName, ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 3).Value, isTraderSeparate, productSeparatedEmails)

skipIteration:
        'resetes traderSeparate Bool/firmNeedExcelConfirm for continued iteration. firmRun bool resets each iteration automatically
        isTraderSeparate = False
        firmNeedExcelConfirm = False
        productSeparatedEmails = False

    Next

    contactsMaster.Columns(40).ClearContents
    contactsMaster.Columns(41).ClearContents
    contactsMaster.Columns(42).ClearContents
    contactsMaster.Columns(43).ClearContents

    MsgBox ("EOD Confirm Emails generated successfully!")

    Exit Sub

Bail_Out:

    MsgBox ("Error occurred when generating " & currentFirmName & " PDF confirm email. Please verify that customer information is input across all forms and try again....Memory Manager will pick up from last email generated")

End Sub
Private Sub GetExcelConfirms(ByRef outMail As MailItem, ByVal currentFirmName As String, ByVal firmName1 As String, ByVal firmName2 As String, ByVal firmName3 As String)

    Dim excelFilePath As String
    Dim excelFileTypeDesignation As String

    excelFileTypeDesignation = ".xls"

    excelFilePath = BuildFileAddress(currentFirmName, , excelFileTypeDesignation)

    If Len(Dir(excelFilePath)) <> 0 Then

        outMail.Attachments.Add (excelFilePath)

    Else

        excelFilePath = BuildFileAddress(firmName1, , excelFileTypeDesignation)

        If Len(Dir(excelFilePath)) <> 0 Then

            outMail.Attachments.Add (excelFilePath)

        Else

            excelFilePath = BuildFileAddress(firmName2, , excelFileTypeDesignation)

            If Len(Dir(excelFilePath)) <> 0 Then

                outMail.Attachments.Add (excelFilePath)

            Else

                excelFilePath = BuildFileAddress(firmName3, , excelFileTypeDesignation)

                If Len(Dir(excelFilePath)) <> 0 Then

                    outMail.Attachments.Add (excelFilePath)

                Else

                    MsgBox ("Unable to locate " & currentFirmName & "'s excel confirm file.  Please attach manually...Continuing")

                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BuildAddressMailItem(ByRef outMail As MailItem, ByVal firmEmail As String, ByVal reportDate As String)

    'Builds email with address in preparation for relevant attachments
    Dim signature As String

    'Captures email signarture
    With outMail
        .Display
    End With

    signature = outMail.HTMLBody

    With outMail
        .To = firmEmail
        .Subject = reportDate & " Trades - Eagle Energy Brokers"
        .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri>" & EMAIL_BODY & Application.UserName & signature & "</BODY>"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub GetPDFConfirms(ByRef outMail As MailItem, firmEmail As String, ByVal firmName1 As String, ByVal firmName2 As String, ByVal firmName3 As String, ByVal initialTraderName As String, ByVal isTraderSeparate As Boolean, ByVal productSeparatedEmails As Boolean, ByVal reportsByFirmCurrentRow As Long, ByVal lastRowReportsByFirmSheet As Long)
'Attaches PDFs to addressed/created emails

    Dim reportsByFirmRowCounter As Long
    Dim initialProductDesignation As String, currentProductDesignation As String, currentFirmName As String, currentTraderName As String, currentDealID As String, pdfAddress As String, fileType As String
    Dim sameFirmBool As Boolean

    initialProductDesignation = ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmCurrentRow, 3).Value
    fileType = ".pdf"

    For reportsByFirmRowCounter = reportsByFirmCurrentRow To lastRowReportsByFirmSheet

        currentFirmName = ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 5).Value
        currentDealID = ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 1).Value
        currentProductDesignation = ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 1).Value
        currentTraderName = ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 6).Value

        'Top level analysis must be same firm..if not...Skip to next row
        If currentFirmName <> firmName1 And currentFirmName <> firmName2 And currentFirmName <> firmName3 Then
            GoTo skipToNext

        Else

            'If employees receive separate emails
            Select Case isTraderSeparate

                Case False

                    'If different groups receive receipts for different products
                    Select Case productSeparatedEmails

                        Case False

                            pdfAddress = BuildFileAddress(currentFirmName, currentDealID, fileType)

                        Case True

                            'Crude and crude products
                            If Left(initialProductDesignation, 2) = "LO" Or Left(initialProductDesignation, 2) = "OS" Or Left(initialProductDesignation, 2) = "CL" Then

                                If Left(currentProductDesignation, 2) = "LO" Or Left(initialProductDesignation, 2) = "OS" Then

                                    pdfAddress = BuildFileAddress(currentFirmName, currentDealID, fileType)

                                ElseIf Left(currentProductDesignation, 2) <> "LN" Or Left(currentProductDesignation, 2) <> "ON" Then

                                    pdfAddress = BuildFileAddress(currentFirmName, currentDealID, fileType)

                                Else
                                    GoTo skipToNext

                                End If

                             'Natural Gas
                            ElseIf Left(initialProductDesignation, 2) = "LN" Or Left(initialProductDesignation, 2) = "ON" Then

                                If Left(currentProductDesignation, 2) = "LN" Or Left(currentProductDesignation, 2) = "ON" Then

                                    pdfAddress = BuildFileAddress(currentFirmName, currentDealID, fileType)
                                Else
                                    GoTo skipToNext

                                End If

                            End If

                    End Select

                Case True

                    If currentTraderName = initialTraderName Then

                        pdfAddress = BuildFileAddress(currentFirmName, currentDealID, fileType)

                    ElseIf currentTraderName <> initialTraderName Then

                        sameFirmBool = IsTraderSameFirm(currentTraderName, firmEmail, currentFirmName)

                        Select Case sameFirmBool

                            Case True

                                pdfAddress = BuildFileAddress(currentFirmName, currentDealID, fileType)

                            Case False

                                GoTo skipToNext
                        End Select

                    End If

            End Select

        End If

        'Attaches pdf confirm or notifies thet user that a confirm was not found and they need to do so manually later
        If pdfAddress <> "Not Found" Then

            With outMail
                .Attachments.Add (pdfAddress)
            End With

        Else

            MsgBox ("Deal ID " & currentDealID & " pdf confirm was not found for " & currentFirmName & ". Please attach manually...continuing")

        End If

skipToNext:
    Next

End Sub

Private Function IsTraderSameFirm(traderName As String, firmEmail As String, firmName As String) As Boolean
    'Finds separate trader email and compares to current email to find if same distribution
    Dim traderFinder As Range, firmFinder As Range
    Dim columnCounter As Long

    columnCounter = 1

    While firmFinder Is Nothing

        Set firmFinder = contactsMaster.Columns(columnCounter).Find(firmName)

        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
    Wend

    Set traderFinder = contactsMaster.Rows(firmFinder.Row).Find(traderName)

    If traderFinder Is Nothing Then

        IsTraderSameFirm = False

    ElseIf traderFinder.Offset(0, 1).Value = firmEmail Then

        IsTraderSameFirm = True

    Else

        IsTraderSameFirm = False

    End If


End Function

Private Function BuildFileAddress(ByVal firmName As String, Optional ByVal dealID As String, Optional ByVal fileType As String) As String
    'Builds file address and tests for it's existence

    Dim formattedFirmName As String, fileAddressProxy As String, dealProxy As String, excelDate As String
    Dim dealArray() As String
    Dim dealTradesMasterLocation As Range

    formattedFirmName = FormatFirm(firmName)

    If fileType = ".pdf" Then

        'Locates the trade by Deal ID number in tradesMaster list to determine if trade was done on CME or NYMEX. Deal proxy is meant to act as a format holder for dealIDs
        If InStr(1, dealID, "-") > 0 Then

            dealArray() = Split(dealID, "-")

            Set dealTradesMasterLocation = TradesMasterSheet.Columns(2).Find(CLng(Trim(dealArray(0))))

            dealProxy = Trim(dealID)

        Else

            Set dealTradesMasterLocation = TradesMasterSheet.Columns(2).Find(CLng(Trim(dealID)))

            dealProxy = Trim(dealID) & "-" & Trim(dealID)

        End If


        'Determines designation of exchange (CME or ICE or otherwise) and sets address proxy
        Select Case TradesMasterSheet.Cells(dealTradesMasterLocation.Row, 6).Value

            Case "Clearport"

                fileAddressProxy = PDF_FILE_PATH & formattedFirmName & "\" & FormattedReportDate & "_" & dealProxy & "_" & formattedFirmName & CME_DESIGNATION & fileType

            Case "ICE"

                fileAddressProxy = PDF_FILE_PATH & formattedFirmName & "\" & FormattedReportDate & "_" & dealProxy & "_" & formattedFirmName & ICE_DESIGNATION & fileType

            Case "NASDAQ"

        End Select

    ElseIf fileType = ".xls" Then

        excelDate = Replace(Format(Range("printinvdate"), "mm/d/yy"), "/", ".")

        fileAddressProxy = EXCEL_CONFIRM_FILE_PATH & "-" & FormatFirm(firmName) & " " & excelDate & Trim(fileType)

    End If

    'Testing for unfound file addresses...if unfound will boot message to user in attachment function
    If Len(Dir(fileAddressProxy)) <> 0 Then

        BuildFileAddress = fileAddressProxy

    Else

        BuildFileAddress = "Not Found"

    End If

End Function

Private Function GetFirmEmailInfo(ByVal reportsByFirmRowCounter As Long, currentFirmName As String, ByVal traderName As String, ByRef isTraderSeparate As Boolean, ByRef firmNeedExcelConfirm As Boolean, ByRef firmName1, ByRef firmName2, ByRef firmName3, ByRef productSeparatedEmails As Boolean) As String
'Finds and sets firm names and returns contact information
'Attempts to find firm in contacts master in the first column...upon failed set of object...tries twice more before requesting input from the user

    Dim firmFinder As Range, traderFinder As Range
    Dim columnCounter As Long

    On Error GoTo FatalErrorInGetEmailInfoFunction

    columnCounter = 1

    'Checks 3 firmname columns for firmname.  If not set prompts user for email
    While firmFinder Is Nothing

        Set firmFinder = contactsMaster.Columns(columnCounter).Find(currentFirmName)

        If columnCounter = 3 And firmFinder Is Nothing Then GoTo PromptForEmail

        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
    Wend

    'Stops execution if firm does not receive email confirms
    If IsEmpty(contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 7)) = False Then
        GetFirmEmailInfo = "NO"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Separated emails by product
    If IsEmpty(contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 4)) = False Then

        productSeparatedEmails = True

        If InStr(ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 3), "LN") = 0 Or InStr(ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 3), "ON") = 0 Then

            If contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 4) = "Crude Oil:" Then

                GetFirmEmailInfo = contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 5)

            Else
                GetFirmEmailInfo = contactsMaster.Cells((firmFinder.Row + 1), 5).Value
            End If

        ElseIf InStr(ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 3), "LN") > 0 Or InStr(ReportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 3), "ON") > 0 Then

            If contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 4) = "Natural Gas:" Then

                GetFirmEmailInfo = contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 5)

            Else

                GetFirmEmailInfo = contactsMaster.Cells((firmFinder.Row + 1), 5)

            End If
        End If

    End If

    firmName1 = contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 1).Value
    firmName2 = contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 2).Value
    firmName3 = contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 3).Value

    'Checks for separate trader emails.....If cell filled isTraderSeparate = true
    'Checks for firm requirement of excel confirms
    If IsEmpty(contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 6)) = False Then isTraderSeparate = True
    If IsEmpty(contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 8)) = False Then firmNeedExcelConfirm = True

    Select Case isTraderSeparate

        Case False

            GetFirmEmailInfo = contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 5).Value

        Case True

            'If traderSeparate is true...finds individual email specific to that trader by searching the rest of the row
            Set traderFinder = contactsMaster.Rows(firmFinder.Row).Find(traderName)
            GetFirmEmailInfo = traderFinder.Offset(0, 1).Value

    End Select

Exit Function

PromptForEmail:
    GetFirmEmailInfo = InputBox("Firm email not found...Please input email for confirm distribution")
    MsgBox ("Please add firm to Contacts Master after completion of Sub to avoid further email contact requests")
    firmName1 = currentFirmName

    Exit Function

FatalErrorInGetEmailInfoFunction:
    GetFirmEmailInfo = "info@eaglecommodities.com"

End Function

Private Function FirmDidRun(ByVal firmName As String, ByVal traderName As String, ByRef productType As String) As Boolean
'Checks memory manager range to see if firm's email has already been generated
    Dim firmFinder As Range
    Dim traderFinder As Range

    Set firmFinder = contactsMaster.Columns(40).Find(firmName)

    If firmFinder Is Nothing Then

        FirmDidRun = False

    ElseIf firmFinder.Offset(0, 2) = "traderS" Then

        Set traderFinder = contactsMaster.Columns(41).Find(traderName)

        If traderFinder Is Nothing Then

            FirmDidRun = False

        Else
            FirmDidRun = True

        End If


    ElseIf firmFinder.Offset(0, 3) = "Crude" Then

        If InStr(1, productType, "LN", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, productType, "ON", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            FirmDidRun = False

        Else

            FirmDidRun = True

        End If

    ElseIf firmFinder.Offset(0, 3) = "NatGas" Then

        If InStr(1, productType, "LN", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, productType, "ON", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            FirmDidRun = True

        Else

            FirmDidRun = False

        End If

    Else

        FirmDidRun = True

    End If
End Function

Private Function FormatFirm(ByVal nameToTrim As String) As String

    On Error Resume Next

    nameToTrim = Trim(Left(nameToTrim, 20))
    While Right(nameToTrim, 1) = "." Or Right(nameToTrim, 1) = " "
        nameToTrim = Left(nameToTrim, Len(nameToTrim) - 1)
    Wend

    FormatFirm = nameToTrim

End Function

Private Sub MemoryManager(ByRef firmName1 As String, ByRef firmName2 As String, ByRef firmName3 As String, ByRef currentTraderName As String, ByRef productType As String, ByRef isTraderSeparate As Boolean, ByRef productSeparatedEmails As Boolean)

    Dim lRowMemoryManagerCol As Long

    lRowMemoryManagerCol = contactsMaster.Cells(contactsMaster.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row

    contactsMaster.Cells((lRowMemoryManagerCol + 1), 40).Value = firmName1
    contactsMaster.Cells((lRowMemoryManagerCol + 1), 41).Value = currentTraderName

    If isTraderSeparate = True Then contactsMaster.Cells((lRowMemoryManagerCol + 1), 42).Value = "traderS"

    If productSeparatedEmails = True Then

        If InStr(1, productType, "LN", vbTextCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, productType, "ON", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

            contactsMaster.Cells((lRowMemoryManagerCol + 1), 43).Value = "Crude"

        Else

            contactsMaster.Cells((lRowMemoryManagerCol + 1), 43).Value = "NatGas"

        End If

    End If

    contactsMaster.Cells((lRowMemoryManagerCol + 2), 40).Value = firmName2
    contactsMaster.Cells((lRowMemoryManagerCol + 3), 40).Value = firmName3

End Sub
```

Comment: @Raystafarian Added to the above!  Thanks!

Comment: So there's a sheet with data that has receipts available somewhere. You want to take the data, get the receipts and mail it (with the summary data) to the specified client?

Comment: @Raystafarian There's a sheet with a summary data of transactions completed for the day.  This code takes that data, gets the specific receipts, attaches them to an email addressed to the relevant client with the receipts.  It does this for each client that did business that day one at a time.  So it iterates through the "summary" sheet or "ReportsByFirmSheet" and then iterates through it again in a second for loop attaching the relevant receipts for that company.

Comment: `gen_report` doesn't seem to exist

Comment: gen_report is an legacy macro that refreshes the "ReportsByFirmSheet"  I didn't include it because I did not write it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Const EMAIL_BODY As String = "Hello," & "<br><br>" & "Please find today's business receipt's attached.  Thank you." & "<br><br>" & "Best Regards," & "<br>"
```

Is there a reason you're using `<br>` instead of `vbLf` or similar?

---

Declaring variables on the same line like this

```
Dim firmAlreadyRun As Boolean, isTraderSeparate As Boolean, firmNeedExcelConfirm As Boolean, productSeparatedEmails As Boolean
```

Is, in my opinion, bad practice. It's **great** that you've given them all a type, but why not give each variable its own line - it's free and increases readability.

```
firmName1
```

It's usually an indication that your variables aren't named descriptively enough when you include a number in them. This could mean it should be `firstFirm` or `currentFirm` or `nextFirm` - however you want to do it so that it's easier to follow.

On the same note, I don't see many variables with names that aren't descriptive enough - so great job on most of your naming!

---

```
If firmAlreadyRun = True Then
```

Doing something like `If method = True then` is redundant, you can just say `If method then`.

---

In the same vein something like

```
If IsEmpty(contactsMaster.Cells(firmFinder.Row, 6)) = False
```

could probably just be `If Not IsEmpty() Then`

---

```
Call BuildAddressMailItem(outMail, firmEmail, FormattedReportDate)
```

You don't need to `Call` subs, it's obsolete. Instead just use `Sub argument, argument`

---

Up top -

```
Dim FormattedReportDate As String
Dim ReportsByFirmSheet As Worksheet, ControlPanelSheet As Worksheet, TradesMasterSheet As Worksheet
```

It's usually better to `Private` them rather than `Dim` just for clarity.

At the same time - you are mostly rocking [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) with `pascalCase`, `CamelCase` and `SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE` in the correct places.

---

```
Private Sub GetExcelConfirms
```

This one seems like [arrow code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) and could probably be replaced with a `SELECT CASE`.

---

In `GetPDFConfirms` you're using

```
If currentFirmName <> firmName1 And currentFirmName <> firmName2 And currentFirmName <> firmName3 Then GoTo skipToNext
```

Seems like you might be better off moving that outside of the loop instead of needing to use the `label:`.

Comment: I was using `<BR>` for the HTML body of the email in order to capture the signature image.  Using a text body doesn't capture the HTML image.  I'm not familiar with `vbLF`; what is the difference?

Comment: @StormsEdge it's [linefeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223228/differences-between-vblf-vbcrlf-vbcr-constants) - but if your email body is all html, then do what you gotta.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of things I noticed on a quick read through:

You're setting the globally scoped `FormattedReportDate` in (I think) the main `Sub` and then sometimes passing it as an argument and sometimes not.  You're right in wanting to pass it as an argument, you just haven't done so consistently:

---

In `BuildAddressMailItem`, you correctly pass `FormattedReportDate` as an argument.

In `BuildFileAddress`, you use the global variable `FormattedReportDate` which makes your code difficult (albeit only slightly) to change if you later decide to format the date differently in different places or decide to use an all-together different date for some parts in the future.

In this small of code, it isn't as big of a deal, but becomes important very quickly as the code size grows.

---

`BuildAddressMailItem` was suprisingly difficult for me to understand.  It took me at least 3 read throughs to understand that you were setting `.HTMLBody` = NewTextStuff & **`.HTMLBody`**

I would write it something like:

```
Private Sub SendPdfEmails()
.
.. 
...

    'Creates new email object
    Set outMail = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'outMail.To should be set here just so there is one less parameter and
    'variable floating around that the programmer needs to keep track of in
    'their head 
    outMail.To = firmEmail

    'This may need to go into its own Sub eventually, but for now, this
    'one-liner is simpler than defining and calling a new Sub.
    outMail.Subject = FormattedReportDate & " Trades - Eagle Energy Brokers"

    WrapHTMLBody(outMail)

...
.. 
.
End Sub

'This Sub has 1 purpose and its name now describes that 
Private Sub WrapHTMLBody(ByRef outMail As MailItem)

    'Using `With` here actually increseases the LOCs and made me do a double-take.
    Call outMail.Display

    'Now that this Sub has a single responsibility using `With` is not much
    'of an advantage over just typing `outMail`
    outMail.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                       EMAIL_BODY & _
                       Application.UserName & _
                       outMail.HTMLBody & _
                       "</BODY>"

End Sub
```

I'm not the best (or any good at all!), but that significantly reduces the number of lines of code and makes it easier to comprehend on first glance (IMHO).